# mysqli_fetch_assoc return nothing on screen

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing the issue with mysql_fetch_assoc function, I need to fetch the data in database with php `mysql_fetch_assoc` function but it is return nothing (blank page), below is my code:

function:

```
function confirm_query($watever){
    global $connection;
    if (!$watever) {
        die("Database query failed! " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

}


 function find_admin(){
    global $connection;

    $query  = "select * from admins ";
    $query .= "order by username asc";

    $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($admin_set);
    return $admin_set;

}
```

admin page:

```
 <?php $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $name, $password, $db); ?>
<?php $admin_set = find_admin(); ?>

<table>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username:</th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Action:</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin_set)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($admin["username"]);?></td>
            <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php echo urldecode($admin["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo urldecode($admin["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure');">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is `confirm_query` ?

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you, confirm_query is a function check connection:

function confirm_query($watever){
    global $connection;
    if (!$watever) {
        die("Database query failed! " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

}

Comment: Have you confirmed that `admin_set` actually contains any data? `print_r($admin_set); exit;` after your `mysqli_query` line

Comment: Please include any additional information, such as the table structure, in your question. Don't link to third party image hosting sites or live pages currently reproducing the error, as you're going to *fix* those pages and render this question useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chek your $connection variable

The results of the same code.

http://gnuhacker.cafe24.com/qna/24730379.php

Souce Code.

http://gnuhacker.cafe24.com/qna/24730379.phps

```
<?PHP
/***
 Database Schema : Mysql 5.1.45

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `admins` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (1, 'test1', 'test1'), (2, 'test2', 'test2');

***/
//$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection)); 


$host = "localhost";
$name = "user";
$db = "database";
$password ="password";
function confirm_query($watever){
    global $connection;
    if (!$watever) {
        die("Database query failed! " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}

 function find_admin(){
    global $connection;

    $query  = "select * from admins ";
    $query .= "order by username asc";

    $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($admin_set);
    return $admin_set;
}
?>
<?php $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $name, $password, $db); ?>
<?php $admin_set = find_admin(); ?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username:</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Action:</th>
</tr>
<?php while($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin_set)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($admin["username"]);?></td>
    <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php echo urldecode($admin["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo urldecode($admin["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure');">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` will **never** return `false` so your `or die()` is useless

Comment: @Phil ok, in this url [mysqli.connect-error.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be with the below code

```
 $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

It should be like below code

```
  $admin_set = mysqli_query($query,$connection);
```

First you need to specify the query and then its connection.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the response. I have changed to $admin_set = mysqli_query($query,$connection); it's threw errors.

Comment: Might want to check the documentation on that one ~ http://php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php